# UserDetailsChecker implementation to override isAccountNotLocked method

Tags: spring-security

I am using UserDetails implementation for authentication which has methods

```
@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

If I set isAccountNonLocked() to return false I am unable to log in anymore.
How can I implement own UserDetailsChecker to override exceptions thrown on checks and where I put my custom UserDetailsChecker, because I am not sure how this preauthentication checks work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a custom `UserDetailsChecker`, you would wire that up when configuring the `AuthenticationManager`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(dao());
    }

    AuthenticationProvider dao() {
         DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
         provider.setPreAuthenticationChecks(new MyUserDetailsChecker());
         return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        // ... expose a UserDetailsService
    }
}
```

Note that you might already be publishing a `UserDetailsService` in another way, but I've included it here as a reminder that the authentication provider needs one in order to work.